# FabricJs clip only drawing not images

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

I use this code to clip canvas in FabricJS:

```
var mask='<svg width="760" height="406" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><g><ellipse fill="#c2c2C2" stroke-width="0" stroke-dasharray="null" stroke-linejoin="null" stroke-linecap="null" cx="380.00004" cy="203.00001" id="svg_1" rx="375.11113" ry="198.22223" stroke="null"/></g></svg>';
var canvas=new fabric.Canvas("canvas");
fabric.loadSVGFromString(mask, function(objects, options) {
var loadedObject = fabric.util.groupSVGElements(objects, options);
loadedObject.set({left:0,top:0});
canvas.clipTo = function(ctx) {
    loadedObject.render(ctx);
};
canvas.renderAll();
});
```

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pes2q387/)

I want only drawings to be clipped not the ribbon image.

Thank you